# Visual Studio 2013 database compatible

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

What SQL Server is compatible with Visual Studio 2013? Is SQL Server 2012 compatible with Visual Studio 2013? Can you give me a site to download SQL Server 2012 that is compatible in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: This is probably off-topic. So you know, the vast majority of Visual Studio versions are compatible with MsSql using OLE or entity framework. I think you should use the free SQL Express.

Comment: Please use tags that are actually related to your problem - spamming unrelated programming languages tags is not well received. It's not clear what your problem is - Visual Studio as such has no compatibility to a specific version of SQL Server. Could it be that you are asking about the SQL Server Data Tools Addon for Visual Studio?

Comment: sorry im just new in here and im just  starting to code. :)

Comment: What do you mean by compatible in this case?

Comment: well im trying to install ms sql server 2012 in my pc but it wont install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 is compatible with all SQL Server editions supported by Microsoft.
Today, SQL Servers starting with 2008 R2 are supported

Reference :
[SQL Server Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/plan-design/configs/support-for-sql-server-versions)